# Force to zoom app in iOS9

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, xcode7

I have an app that in iPhone 6 I want it to be scaled proportionally and zoomed. 
Basically I want to imitate the Applied ZOOM from Settings. At the moment, when I run the app with the Zoom mode from Settings, everything works fine but when I run it without that Zoom from Settings, the views displayed are smaller. How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the view type you want to zoom in ?

Comment: UIView. The whole app is rescaled and plenty of content remains unused. I have this problem only on iOS9

Comment: Do you mean that objects like button, textfields etc. aren't zoomed while the UIView is zoomed ?

Comment: No, all the content is not zoomed

Comment: I don't use size classes and I don't use autolayout. I want the app to display the same content scaled from iPhone 5 to 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved just by adding the name Default-568h@2x.png for one of my launch images and now my app is scaled.I have to say that I didn't have a Storyboard launch screen file set. I was able to manage this thanks to the letterbox hint from @PetahChristian.

> As for the black borders, you must provide some launch images, or iOS will think your app doesn't even support the 4" iPhones and letterbox it

Comment: You answered your second question, but didn't provide an answer to the original question. :)  The answer for the original question is to *not* use a storyboard launch screen file.  You should improve your answer by also providing that information!

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's [What's New in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014205-SW44) documentation:

> To let the system know that your app supports the iPhone 6 screen sizes, include a storyboard launch screen file in your app’s bundle. At runtime, the system looks for a storyboard launch screen file. If such an file is present, the system assumes that your app supports the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus explicitly and runs it in fullscreen mode. If such an image is not present, the system reports a smaller screen size (either 320 by 480 points or 320 by 568 points) so that your app’s screen-based calculations continue to be correct. The contents are then scaled to fit the larger screen.

If you don't supply a launch screen file, (and also don't provide launch screen images for the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus), your app will be scaled instead of running in full screen mode.

*Apple does recommend using size classes and Auto Layout so your app's UI* would *adapt.  Your users may be dissatisfied with your choice to scale your app, as you will not be taking advantage of the larger screen sizes on these newer devices.*

Comment: So in order to achieve the result described, i must implement size classes and autolayout from what I understood.

Comment: I do not present a launch screen nor images and my app displayed has black borders on top and on bottom.

Comment: No.  You can scale your app, as is, without having to use size classes and Auto Layout, by not using a launch screen file.  I only said that this is not recommended.  As for the black borders, you must provide *some* launch images, or iOS will think your app doesn't even support the 4" iPhones and letterbox it.  But if you're learning how to do this, learn the better way.  Use Auto Layout and size classes.  In the long run, it will save you much time and effort if you plan to maintain or upgrade this app.