# How to scale iOS app for different sizes

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, size-classes, adaptive-layout

I'm writing an iOS app and I want app looks similar in iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 Plus.
I know about Auto Layouts, Adaptive Layout and Size Classes.
Is there any other way to scale view from iPhone 5 to larger screen sizes?

It is not so hard to write simple view container scaling for different screen sizes but... how to scale table cells, fonts in buttons, labels?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Are the tools you have mentioned inadequate? Is there a reason you don't want to use auto layout? Is there something specific you are trying to accomplish which you don't think is possible with auto layout?

Comment: I found what I need
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32695120/force-to-zoom-app-in-ios9?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you heard about [AsyncDisplayKit](http://asyncdisplaykit.org)? It has its own unique approach to the question of [layouts](http://asyncdisplaykit.org/docs/layout2-conversion-guide.html), sizes and etc. It also has its own implementation of tables, collections, labels... It took me not much time to replace UICollectionView in existing project with ASCollectionNode.

Hope this helps (:

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it